# gcp remote artifact registry doesn't pull from central

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

in Google cloud Artifact Registry I ve created registry setup using maven type and remote functionality that supposed to mirror central.

It just doesn't work. My local test project is not able to fetch anything from such registry - I assume it should populate gcp registry cache from maven central and propagate any artifacts to my local .m2 directory.

In GCP web console remote type is marked as private preview - which is not really explained what it really means. I can definitely access this config, so I assume it should work :/

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already mentioned in the [public document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/remote-repo#docker) that, `GCP remote Artifact Registry` is not Generally available for all customers.

> **Feature availability:** This feature is only available to users who signed up for Artifact Registry private preview. For more information, contact your Google representative.

And the term `Private Preview` means features are ready for testing by customers and have limited support. But, they are not complete yet.

Have a look at this document for details about [launching stages](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages)